# Joomla breadcrumbs only shows "Home"

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I'm using the built-in Joomla! breadcrumb module, but nothing shows up but "Home" on all my pages.

I looked @ the internals of the module, and inside /modules/mod_breadcrumbs/helper.php

```
    $pathway = &$mainframe->getPathway();
    $items   = $pathway->getPathWay();
```

When I do a print_r on $items, the only thing in the array is "Home". My menus and sub-menus work fine, my urls show up as http://foobar.com/foo/bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I failed to set a default menu, this caused all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your menu structure. I don't remember exactly how the breadcrumbs work, but it should run off the main menu. Do you need to make your menu items sub-menu items of "Home"?

EDIT: on second thoughts, I'm pretty sure it runs off the Section/Category listings. So you'd need to categorise all your articles.

Answer (score 0):

This is joomla 1.5 breadcrumbs concept

$pathway  =& $mainframe->getPathway();

$pathway->addItem( JText::_( 'Your Uploads' ),'index.php?option=com_useruploads');

$pathway->addItem('Edit Product');